# In a Spring Boot project, obtaining SqlSession from Druid is very fast, but the subsequent JDBC connections are very slow

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Environment:

1. Operating Environment: Linux + K8S
2. Database: Oracle
3. Druid Version: 1.1.0

I encountered a strange issue in my Spring Boot application. I'm using the Druid connection pool to connect to an Oracle database. Occasionally, I observe that retrieving the `SqlSession` from the Druid connection pool is fast, but the subsequent JDBC execution is very slow. It takes around 10 minutes or more. Can anyone please help me with this?

Log images:
[log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sCMP.png)

Project config:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    druid:
      url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.10:1521:prod
      initial-size: 10
      max-active: 20
      min-idle: 1
      max-wait: 60000
      pool-prepared-statements: true
      max-pool-prepared-statement-per-connection-size: 20
      validation-query: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
      test-on-borrow: false
      test-on-return: false
      test-while-idle: true
      time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 60000
      min-evictable-idle-time-millis: 30000
      remove-abandoned: true       
      remove-abandoned-timeout: 60 
      web-stat-filter:
        enabled: true
        url-pattern: /*
        #exclusions: *.js,*.gif,*.jpg,*.png,*.css,*.ico,/druid/*
        session-stat-enable: false
        session-stat-max-count: 1000
        profile-enable: true
        principal-session-name: admin
        principal-cookie-name: admin
      stat-view-servlet:
        enabled: true
        url-pattern: /druid/*
        reset-enable: true
        login-username: user1
        login-password: user1
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    username: user1
    password: user1
```

Please help to take a look, I have not yet found a solution